# How to remove labels autospacing

Tags: css, html, forms, label

I have make this custom menu with labels, but i can't removing this auto spacing from labels =/

http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/ijCsa

Can anyone help me? Thanks in adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want them to touch each other, this will work:

```
label {display: block; float: left;}
```